# React Flowtype Node.contains() Event Target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have this event listener in React:

```
document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleDocumentClick);
```

This is one of the definitions of this method as per [Flow's source code](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.63.1/lib/dom.js):

```
removeEventListener(type: MouseEventTypes, listener: MouseEventListener, optionsOrUseCapture?: EventListenerOptionsOrUseCapture): void;
```

It seems the listener must be of type `MouseEventListener`:

```
type MouseEventHandler = (event: MouseEvent) => mixed
type MouseEventListener = {handleEvent: MouseEventHandler} | MouseEventHandler
```

So it seems that I can type it like this:

```
handleDocumentClick = (evt: MouseEvent) => {

}
```

So far, no Flow errors. Now, I want to check if the event's target is inside another DOM node that I have stored in a [React Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
$menu: React.ElementRef<typeof Menu>;

handleDocumentClick = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
    if (this.$menu !== null) {
        const menu = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.$menu);

        if (menu) {
            console.log(menu.contains(evt.currentTarget));
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
 54:                     console.log(menu.contains(evt.currentTarget));
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ EventTarget. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
447:   contains(other: ?Node): boolean;
                        ^^^^ Node. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_3e761601/dom.js:447
```

The `contains` method should work for the target of an event (which is a DOM node). What could be wrong here – perhaps the definition of `contains` in Flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple options, the easiest of which is probably just:

```
handleDocumentClick = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
    if (this.$menu !== null) {
        const menu = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.$menu);

        if (menu && evt.currentTarget instanceof Node) {
            console.log(menu.contains(evt.currentTarget));
        }
    }
}
```

But you can always cast `currentTarget` (you can cast to `Node`, but you'll need to cast to `any` first):

```
handleDocumentClick = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
    if (this.$menu !== null) {
        const menu = findDOMNode(this.$menu)

        if (menu) {
            // console.log(menu.contains(((evt.currentTarget: any): Node)))
            console.log(menu.contains((evt.currentTarget: any)))
        }
    }
}
```

The first option will protect in case you end up with some weird edge case (and you could always add a utility function like `isNode` or something to use repeatedly).

Answer (score 0):

The property currentTarget is inherited from Event, which can have references to types other than Node.